# Python multiplication quiz syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, multiplication

while writing a program which overall creates a quiz of 10 multiplication questions for a user, I have encountered a syntax error which I have been unsuccessful in fixing. When I try to run the code, there is a syntax error, pointing to the colon after "if userAns == numAns:" Here is my code:

```
import random
numOne = 0
numTwo = 0
numRight = 0
numProblems = 0
numAns = 0
userAns = 0

while numProblems < 10:
    numProblems+=1
    numOne = random.randint(0,100)
    numTwo = random.randint(0,100)
    numAnswer = numOne*numTwo
    userAnswer = int(input("What is:",numOne,"*",numTwo,"?")
    if userAns == numAns:
        numRight += 1
if numRight >0<3:
    print("That was pretty bad.. ")
elif numRight >3 and numRight<=6:
    print("Hey not bad..")
elif numRight >6 and numRight <=9:
    print("You're pretty good....")
elif numRight == 10:
    print("OK OK...You're smarter than me...")
else:
    print("ERROR")
```

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Side note, the user can never be right (wrong?) since you set `userAnswer` and check `userAns`, also 0 is always less than 3

Comment: Regarding `if numRight >0<3:`: Did you mean `if 0 <= numRight <= 3:`? BTW, please check the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues on line `userAnswer = ...`:

- Missing parentheses at the end
- `input` requires a single argument

In order to fix these, try this:

```
userAnswer = int(input("What is: {} * {}? ".format(numOne, numTwo)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This line needs a right bracket.

```
userAnswer = int(input("What is:",numOne,"*",numTwo,"?"))
```

And you'd better write the hint message like this:

```
...
while numProblems < 10:
    numProblems+=1
    numOne = random.randint(0,100)
    numTwo = random.randint(0,100)
    numAnswer = numOne*numTwo
    hint = "What is:" + str(numOne) + "*" + str(numTwo) + "?"
    userAnswer = int(input(hint))

    if userAns == numAns:
        numRight += 1
...
```

Comment: Checking `userAns` won't get the user very far... should be `userAnswer` :)